# Activating snapping with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, snapping

I would like to construct a map tool application that allows only to add some point features.

How do I complete the following code to activate snap mode while editing a layer with PyQGIS 3?

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class AddPointTool(QgsMapTool):
   def __init__(self, mapCanvas, layer):
       QgsMapTool.__init__(self, mapCanvas)
       self.layer=layer
       self.setCursor(Qt.CrossCursor)

   def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
       point=self.toLayerCoordinates(self.layer, event.pos())
       fields=self.layer.dataProvider().fields()
       feature=QgsFeature()
       feature.setFields(fields)
       feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(point))

       self.layer.addFeature(feature)
       self.layer.updateExtents()
       self.layer.triggerRepaint()

canvas=iface.mapCanvas()
layer=iface.activeLayer()

layer.startEditing()
layer.triggerRepaint()
tool=AddPointTool(canvas,layer)
canvas.setMapTool(tool)
```

Comment: The following expression enable snapping for PyQGIS 2.0 :
QgsProject.instance().setSnapSettingsForLayer(layer.id(), True, 2, 1, 10, True)
What is the equivalent expression in PyQGIS 3.0?

Comment: did you find any solution ? I would be interested !

Answer (score 6):

I created my own subclass of MapTool in order to solve the snapping issue. I subclassed `QgsMapToolEmitPoint` because I use the `canvasClicked` signal, but other MapTool classes can be simply adapted.

The key point is that instead of other examples I found out on the web, this solution uses the snapping settings of the tool's `QgsMapCanvas` (by means of `self.canvas.snappingUtils()`), so it simply listens to the user's snapping settings in the current working session (including Snapping On/Off, Snap to current/all Layers, Snap to Vertices/Segments/Both, Snap to Intersections On/Off, Snapping Radius, Snapping Indicator Color, ...).

```
class SnappingMapToolEmitPoint(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    snapClicked = pyqtSignal(QgsPointXY, Qt.MouseButton)

    def __init__(self, canvas):
        super().__init__(canvas)
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.canvasClicked.connect(self.snapClick)
        self.snapIndicator = QgsSnapIndicator(canvas)
        self.snapper = self.canvas.snappingUtils()

    def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
        snapMatch = self.snapper.snapToMap(e.pos())
        self.snapIndicator.setMatch(snapMatch)

    @pyqtSlot(QgsPointXY, Qt.MouseButton)
    def snapClick(self, point, button):
        if self.snapIndicator.match().type():
            point = self.snapIndicator.match().point()
        self.snapClicked.emit(point, button)
```

With an instance of this class, I connect the `snapClicked` signal to the function I want to use. It works just like the `canvasClicked` signal of `QgsMapToolEmitPoint`, but returns a snapped point if snapping is enabled.