# Highlighting snapping position in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, snapping, qgsmapcanvas

I'm trying to add points on a line with `QgsMapTool`. I need to show snap indicator (vertex or edge) while moving the mouse on a line.

How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
class uubEditTool(QgsMapToolEdit):
    def __init__(self, canvas, iface, db):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.iface = iface
        QgsMapToolEdit.__init__(self, self.canvas)

        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'FiberManagementSystem_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)
        self.msg = QMessageBox()
        self.rb = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, QgsWkbTypes.PointGeometry)
        self.rb.setStrokeColor(QColor('Purple'))
        self.rb.setWidth(2.0)
        self.first_click = True
        # self.fixed_points = []
        self.deactivated.connect(lambda: self.clean_up)
       
    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
        theUser = ''

        ugr_lyr = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName("Under Ground Route")[0]
        x_point = event.pos().x()
        y_point = event.pos().y()
        point = self.canvas.getCoordinateTransform().toMapCoordinates(x_point, y_point)
        print("point", point)
        click_point = event.snapPoint()

        if event.isSnapped():
            print("UUB is Snapped to UGR")
            if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
                
                self.layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
                new_point = QgsPointXY(point)
                geom = QgsGeometry().fromPointXY(new_point)
                if self.layer.isEditable():
                    source = self.layer.source()
                    kvp = source.split(" ")
                    for kv in kvp:
                        if kv.startswith("user"):
                            theUser = kv.split("=")[1][1:-1]
                    self.layer.beginEditCommand('Add Snapped Feature')
                    fields = self.layer.fields()
                    # gid_field = layer.fields().indexFromName('gid')
                    creat_by = self.layer.fields().indexFromName('created_by')
                    creat_date = self.layer.fields().indexFromName('created_date')
                    uub_name = self.layer.fields().indexFromName('uub_name')
                    uub_latitude = self.layer.fields().indexFromName('latitude')
                    uub_longitude = self.layer.fields().indexFromName('longitude')
                    # make = layer.fields().indexFromName('make')
                    self.feat = QgsFeature()
                    self.feat.setGeometry(geom)
                    self.feat.setFields(self.layer.fields())

                    x = geom.asPoint().x()
                    y = geom.asPoint().y()
                    self.feat[uub_longitude] = round(x, 6)
                    self.feat[uub_latitude] = round(y, 6)
                    d = QgsDistanceArea()
                    d.setEllipsoid('WGS84')

                    layer.addFeature(feat)
                    layer.updateFeature(feat)
                    layer.endEditCommand()
```

Comment: Your script has missing parts, for example, `self.clean_up`. Even if a solution is offered to you, the solution may not work for you without completing the missing parts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following lines to `__init__` method:

```
self.snapIndicator = QgsSnapIndicator(canvas)
self.snapper = self.canvas.snappingUtils()
```

And add a `canvasMoveEvent` method like this:

```
def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
    snapMatch = self.snapper.snapToMap(e.pos())
    self.snapIndicator.setMatch(snapMatch)
```

After running the script, enable snapping from Snapping Toolbar.

[image]

Source: [Activating snapping with PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/355250/29431)

PS: I've removed some lines to run it seamlessly in my QGIS. If your script in the question already works as it is, the solution will work for you.

Answer (score 5):

Above answer will give the snapping for active Layer, for all Layers

```
self.snapper = canvas.snappingUtils()
config = QgsSnappingConfig()
config.setEnabled(True)
config.setType(QgsSnappingConfig.VertexAndSegment)
config.setUnits(QgsTolerance.Pixels)
config.setTolerance(12)
config.setMode(2)
self.snapper.setConfig(config)
self.snapindicator = QgsSnapIndicator(canvas)
```

Comment: I didn't add this detail to my answer, since you didn't particularly mention it.